# NodeJS MySQL - Check if column exists

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In plain Java, it's easy to check if a column exists with `conn.getMetaData()`, but how do you do that in JavaScript?

```
con.connect();
md = con.getMetaData(); //???
rs = md.getColumns(null, null, table, name);
if (!rs.next()) {
    sendUpdateQuery("ALTER TABLE " + table + " ADD " + name + " VARCHAR(100)");
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to connect to the db?

Comment: @YutiZarubin `"mysql": "^2.9.0"`